# Entity Framework Associations: Error Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, dns, entity

Using Entity Framework 4.1

I have the following tables I'm using with Entity Framework

- **User** ( UserId PK identity, UserName, Password )
- **Physician** ( PhysicianId unique identity, UserId refereces User PK, PhysicianName )
- **PhysicianSite** ( SiteId, Location, PhysicianId FK to Physician table)

Problem. Entity Framework would not allow me to associate Physician with PhysicianSite because PhysicianId is not the primary key on the Physician table.

User is the base of Physician because my application has other types Users, such as Patients.

I get the following error

Error   2   Error 113: Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Physician' in relationship 'PhysicianSitePhysician'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be *.

Could someone tell me how I can create the association with Physician to PhysicianSite **in Entity Framework** without PhysicianId being the primary key on the Physician table?

Comment: Question: Why PhysicianId is not the PK of Physician anyways?

Comment: To give Physician the base type of User in Entity Framework you need to set the UserId as primary key of Physician.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework requires foreign keys to link to a table's primary key. However, the primary key to Entity Framework does not have to match the primary key in the database. If you tell EF the PhysicianId is the primary key, it won't go checking if it really is. And it will happily accept foreign keys to the PhysicianId.

If you have some foreign keys to PhysicianId, and others to the real primary key, you're out of luck, but it doesn't seem like you do.

Comment: I have given the Physician a base type of User. In order to do that, I had to make the UserId the primary key of the physician table, which makes sense. I had to inform Entity Framework that the UserId is the primary key of the Physician table, so I can't change that. I think I'm not going to go the inheritance route and simply make an association between the Physician and User rather than the Physician inheriting from the User.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I had overlooked that. In that case, what you want unfortunately simply isn't currently supported by EF. According to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/03/09/unique-constraints-in-the-entity-framework.aspx, there are plans to add it in a future release, but you will have to wait for that.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your all tables from EDMX and Update edmx by adding all tables again. Ef not refresh all navigation properties so it gives such errors

Answer (score 0):

If you have a link table with a column with identity specification, remove that (it would restrict the link table to only one copy of the ID for that linked table).